# Data type of OAuth 2's expires_in field

Tags: oauth-2.0, specifications

The OAuth2 field `expires_in` lists the number of seconds till the token expires.

I have a funky tool (WSO2) that is passing 9223372036854775 as `expires_in` in an attempt to support non-expiring tokens.  That equates to 292,471,208 YEARS in the future!  That large of a number causes some issues with libraries that are expecting an `int` for `expires_in`.

I am trying to understand if this is allowed by the OAuth 2 Specification.  I tried searching for it, but I could not see anything about the data type of `expires_in`.

**Does `expires_in` have a data type in OAuth 2? And if so, what is it?**

Answer (score 1):

So the [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-73) lists `expires_in` as:

```
A.14.  "expires_in" Syntax

   The "expires_in" element is defined in Sections 4.2.2 and 5.1:

     expires-in = 1*DIGIT
```

Digging a bit deeper `1*DIGIT` is using the Augmented Backus–Naur form ([ABNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)).  That takes the format of

```
<a>*<b>DIGIT
```

Where `<a>` is the optional min number of elements and `<b>` is the optional max number of elements.

So, `1*DIGIT` means that it has to be at least one digit long, but is unbounded in the maximum.

So, while a bit crazy, saying that a token expires in the year 292473229 is supported by the spec, just not the library I am using.  (The library, called [IdentityModel](https://github.com/IdentityModel), uses an `int` for `expires_in`.)